# Convert image to red grayscale

Tags: c#

I have a bitmap image that I would like to convert to grayscale, but using red instead of black as the base for the grey.

```
Bitmap formatted = bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  Turning an RGB vector into a scalar value, or taking the scalar value and mapping it onto the "R" channel of a bitmap?  The first part is probably the tricky part - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale should help

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you want to apply a filter and extract the red component from an image.

What you want to do, basically, is to negate the Green and Blue components of a given pixel, and capture only the Red component.

I found a small piece of code that does exactly that. Check the following link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1989/Image-Processing-for-Dummies-with-C-and-GDI-Part-1

Check the session about **Color Filters**. You can download the sourcecode and poke around a bit.

Comment: What I actually want to do is convert every pixel to red with the same opacity

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a brute force approach, but it works:

```
Bitmap formatted = bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
int width = bitmap.Width;
int height = bitmap.Height;
for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
{
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        formatted.SetPixel(w, h, Color.FromArgb(bitmap.GetPixel(w, h).A, bitmap.GetPixel(w, h).R, 0, 0));
    }
}
```